# Codename One Designer - Bezier Corners

Tags: codenameone

In the Codename One Designer, there is the option "Bezier Corners" in the RoundRect. I didn't notice any difference selecting or deselecting it. What does it mean "Bezier Corners" and what is the difference in using or not using this option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not implemented yet, the goal is to create round rects that are more in line with Apple's UX as explained in this article: https://hackernoon.com/apples-icons-have-that-shape-for-a-very-good-reason-720d4e7c8a14

Unfortunately I never got around to do that so the setup for that code is there but the implementation isn't.